# Mention in Discord

Tags: sqlite, discord, discord.js

I ran into a strange problem.
When I take the user id from my database and try to mention the user by it, the id digit is rounded, therefore the mention will not work.

```js
async Run(guild_id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.participantRepository.GetRandomParticipant(guild_id).then(participant => {
            if (participant === null) {
                reject("u cant do this");
                return;
            }

            this.gamesRepository.SaveGameInformation(guild_id, participant.id);
            this.participantRepository.ScoreParticipant(participant.id);
            resolve(Misc.GetRandomElement(resultPhrases) + "<@" + participant.discord_user_id+ ">"); //here is problem!
        });
    });
}
```

[How it looks like in discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEqP4.png)

[In database everything is fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSOyd.png)

see? in database last three numbers is 784, but in discord they become 800

I'm at a loss and can't figure out what can affect this. Help pls

UPD:

GetRandomParticipant() takes 1 random user from a sqlite table

```js
async GetRandomParticipant(guild_id) {
    return this.dbAdapter.get(
        "SELECT id, discord_user_id, discord_user_name FROM participants WHERE discord_guild_id = ?1 ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1",
        {
            1: guild_id
        }
    ).then(result => {
        if (result === undefined) {
            return null;
        }

        return result;
    });
}
```

UPD2:

I found one interesting detail, if I put the real type in db, then it also starts to output 800 in the database table. Could it be that I have somehow converted to the real type during program execution?

[***800.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EGg7.png)

Comment: Please add more information about `GetRandomParticipant()` function

Comment: @mike I updated the post with an explanation of what it does

Comment: What is the data type for the field `discord_user_id` in db?

Comment: @mike First I set the integer type, but there was the same error and I set the string type.The error, as you can see, has not disappeared...

Comment: It has to do with the fact that the user id gets stored as an integer (or at least gets read as an integer after fetching) and it is bigger than the [Max Safe Integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) limit of Javascript. Any number bigger than that can get rounded. The solution would be to store the user id as a string (varchar) in the database

Comment: @T.Dirks In the end, I came to this answer myself, although I did not know the exact explanation for why this happened. But anyway, thank you very much :)
(but with string it didn't work idk why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ABSOLUTELY don't understand how it worked, but when I just went through the options, set
varchar(50) data type for the field `discord_user_id` - everything worked :/